# How to build a shortcode for tabs

Tags: shortcode, tabs

I made a tabbed widget to display recent posts, comments, and popular posts. Now I want to take out the tab function and make a shortcode of it, so I can add it to WP posts and use it there.

```
<div class="tabs tabs-style-topline">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#section-topline-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-topline-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-topline-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-topline-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-topline-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <section id="section-topline-1"><p>1</p></section>
        <section id="section-topline-2"><p>2</p></section>
        <section id="section-topline-3"><p>3</p></section>
        <section id="section-topline-4"><p>4</p></section>
        <section id="section-topline-5"><p>5</p></section>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /tabs -->

<script>
    new CBPFWTabs( document.getElementById( 'tabs' ) );
</script>
```

Built on [this tutorial](http://bit.ly/SZv43p).

Whatever code in `functions.php` I tried in the last two days, it simply won't work. Ideally I want something like this to add inside posts:

```
[tabgroup]
[tab title="Tab 1"]Tab 1 content goes here.[/tab]
[tab title="Tab 2"]Tab 2 content goes here.[/tab]
[tab title="Tab 3"]Tab 3 content goes here.[/tab]
[/tabgroup]
```

Comment: Anyone ? I tried with something like this but it breaks a layout http://pastebin.com/zWEmXTnr

Comment: You might want to check: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabsy/. I'm using similar shortcode layout.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code you shared a little. You can try this: http://pastebin.com/sAshJ348

Change the classes where necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I used a modified version of what you posted and it worked great :D

Minor tweak: in `tab_func` there's no need to return `$single_tab_array` and in my case caused an `Array to string conversion` notice.  

You don't have to return anything, but if you'd prefer it did than you can change the return value from `$single_tab_array` to `$content`. Again, thank you for sharing!